# Skip choose printer dialog screen

Tags: c#, printing

I am working on windows application and in that application I want to print some pages depending on Id.

When I put Id and click on print button, print screen appears where we choose printer.

How do I skip this step?? I want directly print preview screen.

My code:

```
DialogResult result = printdialog.ShowDialog(); 
if (result == DialogResult.OK) 
{ 
   PrintPreviewDialog pp = new PrintPreviewDialog(); 
   pp.Document = pdoc; result = pp.ShowDialog(); 
   if (result == DialogResult.OK) { pdoc.Print(); } 
}
```

Comment: Are you using PrintDialog() instead of Print() ? Is there a default printer assigned?

Comment: DialogResult result = printdialog.ShowDialog();
if (result == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                PrintPreviewDialog pp = new PrintPreviewDialog();
                pp.Document = pdoc;
                result = pp.ShowDialog();
                if (result == DialogResult.OK)
                {
                    pdoc.Print();
                }
            }

Comment: Hmmm, PC is annoyingly obeying instructions provided.

Answer (score 0):

In the code above you're first displaying the print dialog and displaying the preview dialog only after that. If you want preview screen directly you can simply show that window first

Please have a look at this MSDN article: [How to: Print in Windows Forms Using Print Preview](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404294(v=vs.110).aspx)

Taken from the above article:

```
private void printPreviewButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ReadDocument();
    printPreviewDialog1.Document = printDocument1;
    printPreviewDialog1.ShowDialog();
}
```

Comment: Can you please tell me how to add background image in print preview screen.
I have one variable called "back" if back =1 it will show print preview with background image,otherwise it will show plain print preview.